# Could alternatives to Photosynthesis be possible?

Tags: botany, plant-physiology, photosynthesis

I'm working on a world for stories and games, and I'm trying to figure out some more diverse plantlife. There are areas of the world that won't get enough sunlight for Photosynthesis, so I'm thinking about alternatives.

We can use Piezoelectric components to charge batteries, so could Piezosynthesis be possible in plants, if there was enough air movement to, say, move a sail-like fin back and forth enough to generate a similar "power" to photosynthesis?

Comment: I think this is actually a cool question. I don’t have time to give a shot at the answer, but take a look at some thermophilic archaea or some nitrogen fixing fungus and you may be able to get some ideas from that realm. As far as wind-power, that may not be practical—the sail fin idea may seem cool, but my bet is that it wouldn’t generate nearly enough energy for a whole organism even if everything else worked.

Comment: There are whole communities - e.g. undersea vents - based on chemosynthesis: http://noaacontent.nroc.org/lesson05/l5text.htm

Comment: Unfortunately, however interesting the question may be, any answer, by definition, is speculative and hence puts the question off topic on SE Biology. As a reading of the Help will remind users, this is a question and answer site, not a discussion site.

Comment: Then treat the question as "are piezosynthetic plants feasible from a biological standpoint" - speculative or not, it's still a question about biology. The issue I have is that there are very few places where discussion about fiction can occur, where the people are going to be as educated on the subject as they are here.